# BigQuery web interface saying unable to find destination table

Tags: google-bigquery

Occasionally, when using the BigQuery web interface I receive an error banner at the top of the page saying `unable to find destination table: <table_name>` where `table_name` is something like `anon_somerandomgibberish`. I also had this happen when specifying a destination table for a query. Is this due to a temporary issue in the BigQuery service? If so, is there anything that I can do to retrieve the results of the query without having to re-execute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error appears when attempting to show the results of a query and a BigQuery API call to get the table details fails or times out.  This could happen for a number of reasons, such as the table having been deleted or flakiness in the BigQuery service.

If this happens again, you can use the network tab in the Chrome (or another browser's) dev tools to see which API call is failing and with what error.  The URL of the failure should contain the name of the table that the error message complains about.  If you can share those details with us, it can help us determine if there's a bug in the UI or whether something is going wrong with the API service.

If you would like to retrieve the results of a previously run query, you can click on the Query History in the left nav, open the relevant query, and click the "Show Previous Results" button.  Note that this button will only be present if the destination table still exists.  Another option, if you know the full job ID of the query, is to navigate to 
`https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/results/<project_id>:<job_id>`